# "Located in" vs "located at"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

What's the difference between them?

I am interested in a generic definition, but here is the sentence I was writing:

> "The file is located at/in the images folder."

Comment: There's no hard-and-fast rule. For "non-spatial" contexts, and/or where the "location" is commonly thought of as a "container" of some kind, *in* is more likely. Things are more likely to be *at* locations further away, but specific cases vary, and many are quite uncertain. The index, for example can be *at the back of the book*, or *in the back...*. Both usages occur with about equal frequency on that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*in* would refer to a container holding the object.

> The pen lies **in** the box

*at* would refer to the location of the object.

> The box is **at** the shop

In your context, as the folder contains the file, therefore, use of *in* would be appropriate.

Of course, they, at times, can be used interchangeably (Thanks @FumbleFingers). [This](http://www.learnenglish.de/mistakes/atvsin.htm) link gives a nice comparison between the use of *at* and *in*.

Comment: The box can be *in* or *at* the shop. If you were outside the shop (especially if you were either near it, or owned/worked in it) and someone asked where the box was, you'd probably say *in*. If you were further away (spatially or metaphorically), you'd more likely say *at*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will go with `located in the folder` here, which sounds more natural. Files are generally stored **within** the folder of a computer system, so the proposition `in` is more appropriate and accurate than `at`. the proposition `at` usually go with home/office/university/point/stage/time/... these words and so on, indicating where/when exactly things happen.

Answer (score 1):

"Located at" is wrong, and "located in" is not wrong, but I'm reluctant to call it correct because I find "The file is in the images folder" preferable to "The file is located in the images folder."  Also, if you are writing documentation (vs. speaking conversationally) write "File *x* is in the images folder"; that is, name a specific file in the sentence instead of depending on context or a previous reference.

Comment: This sounds like you're asserting that 'located at' is wrong per se. OP opens with a generally scoped question before particularising.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I apparently skipped the more general question.  ... That aside, even if 'located at' isn't always wrong, it often is verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The word "located" is superfluous in this context.  Something is simply "in" a container or "at" at place.  Saying "located at" is poor grammar in the same sense as "revert back".